# Opt out is looping

Tags: civimail

I have a WordPress website and I upgraded from CiviCRM 4.5.8 to 4.7.9 about a month ago and while the action.optOuturl token is still working (it's in the mail footer), today I discovered it just redisplays the opt out page, so the user thinks they have to do it again. The opt out flag is set in the database and an Opt Out Confirmation email is sent to the user.

How do I stop it from redisplaying the opt out page? Thanks...

Comment: C'mon folks, please help me out. I'm getting irate emails from folks trying to opt-out 'cuz it doesn't look like it works. I tried playing with the sandbox version, but it won't send emails. I checked the CMS WordPress Integration setting and it looks correct.

Comment: I concur that entering the email as requested and submitting results in a 'success' message but that the original message of 'you are requesting ..." shows with the same obfuscated (?) email. This seems like something that should be reported in JIRA though I am not certain if this is new behaviour or it it has done this for a long time.

Comment: @petednz I certainly agree...it's terrible the way it is. Can you report it in JIRA? Or tell me how to do it? Thanks

Comment: Jim - here are some links which I hope you find helpful - as a community effort CiviCRM improves as a result of contributions from any of us so it would be great if you can help this get sorted. https://civicrm.org/bug-reporting or https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6/the-civicrm-community/bug-reporting/ or

Comment: I upgraded to 4.7.11 today and the problem went away! Now there's a yellow message on the screen indicating a successful opt out: [opt out screen image](http://wiuta.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Opt-out-screen.png)

Answer (score 2):

I upgraded to 4.7.11 today and the problem went away! See my comment...